# AngularJS remove hash (#) with default param

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have to build this website with multi language, so I insert default parameter in the abstract state, like this:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/en');
var layoutState = {
  'name': 'layout',
  'abstract': true,
  'url': '/:lang',
};
```

Then the homepage state like this:

```
var homeState = {
  'name': 'home',
  'parent': 'layout',
  'templateUrl': './views/home.html',
  'data': {
    'pageTitle': 'Home'
  },
  'controller': 'HomeCtrl as home'
};
```

The url will be rendered like this: `http://test.local/#!/en`

The expected url is: `http://test.local/en`, so I tried this options:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
}).hashPrefix("");
```

But it doesn't receive the `lang` params, and the url is only `http://test.local/`.

Could anyone help me to fix this problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: have you configured your routing (in `.htaccess`)?

Comment: I am new to `.htaccess`. This is my dummy effort but it doesn't work, so I stopped thinking about it. `RewriteRule    ^en/?$    #/en [NC,L]`

Comment: refer this documentation - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8

Comment: The problem is that I want to keep the `:lang` default param for each routes. But if I use `html5Mode:true`, that param is not understood, and it's gonna throw 404 error. Even with `.htaccess`